# Using reactor to manage dependent tasks

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I have a usecase where some messages appear and each of them triggers a set of tasks, some of them may depend on each other, ie. TaskD requires results of TaskA and TaskB, while TaskC is independent of ther tasks and may run in parallel.

Tasks and dependencies for each message may vary, it is configurable per message type. 
It is required that all tasks must complete to store final processing results.

Some pseudo-configuration for dependency management.

[msgType=aa]

- TaskA
- TaskB
- TaskC
- TaskD, depends=TaskA, TaskB

I am using Java 8 and spring-boot.
Can you advice me with best approach to solve this problem cleanly using `reactor`?
Does `reactor` fit here?

Comment: I have simplified the question, after I've got suggestion it is to broad.